# Why does my for loop of month does not give me an accurate reading

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iterator, codeblocks

I am suppose to calculate the average temperature and the standard deviation of each month of the given year.

This is the function to calculate average temp and stdev according to the year given.

```
bool TempCalculation(Vector<Weather> weatherlog, int month, int year, float *averageTemp, float *stdevTemp)
{
    *averageTemp = 0;
    *stdevTemp - 0;
    int dataCount = 0;
    float sumTemp = 0;
    float sumDev = 0;

    // flag is to track whether there are data in the month
    bool flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < weatherlog.Size(); ++i)
    {
        // retrieve date from weather log object
        Date date;
        weatherlog[i].GetDate(date);

        // compare month and year
        if(date.GetMonth() == month && date.GetYear() == year)
        {
            // calculate total sum of temperature of each log of the month and year together
            sumTemp = sumTemp + weatherlog[i].GetTemperature();
            dataCount ++;
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    // if there are data in the month,change value from int to float
    // convert sum of wind speed to km/h, calculate average
    if (flag == true)
    {
        *averageTemp = sumTemp / dataCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < weatherlog.Size(); ++i)
        {
            // retrieve date from weather log object
            Date date;
            weatherlog[i].GetDate(date);

            // compare month and year
            if(date.GetMonth() == month && date.GetYear() == year)
            {
                sumDev += pow((weatherlog[i].GetTemperature() - *averageTemp), 2);
            }
        }

        *stdevTemp = sqrt(sumDev / (dataCount - 1));
    }

    return flag;
}
```

The average temp and standard deviation will be stored in the global variable.

Next, i will call the function to ask the user to input a year and display the required result

```
void CalculateTemp(Vector<Weather> weatherlog)
{
    int year;
    bool flag;

    cout << "\nAverage ambient air temperature and sample standard deviation for each month of a specified year" << endl;
    // get year input from user
    cout<< "\nEnter Year (e.g. 2023): ";
    // check input if invalid
    if (!(cin >> year))
    {
        //clear input if invalid
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        cout << "Invalid Year" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << '\n' << year << endl;
        for(int month = 0; month < 12; month++)
        {
            //get calculation of average wind speed and average temperature
            flag = TempCalculation(weatherlog, month, year, &averageTemp, &stdevTemp);

            // display outcome according to flag
            if (flag == true)
            {
                cout <<  monthArray[month] << ": average: " << averageTemp << " degrees C, stdev: " << stdevTemp << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << monthArray[month] << ": No Data" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the data stored in the system are only March 2016
The required result should look something like this:

```
2016
January: No Data
February: No Data
March: average: 21.7 degrees C, stdev: 2.0
April: No Data
May: No Data
June: No Data
July: No Data
August: No Data
September: No Data
October: No Data
November: No Data
December: No Data
```

However the system is giving me this:

```
2016
January: No Data
February: No Data
March: No Data
April: average: 21.7 degrees C, stdev: 2.0
May: No Data
June: No Data
July: No Data
August: No Data
September: No Data
October: No Data
November: No Data
December: No Data
```

The month in the for loop skip the march and display the it on april instead, i have checked the data stored in the weather object, it display as 3 for the month attribute.

Comment: "it display as 3 for the month attribute" 3 as in the 3rd month (i.e. March), or 3 as in the month at index 3 (i.e. April)? Array/container indices start at 0 in C++. Make sure you're converting between them correctly

Comment: `*stdevTmp - 0 ;` looks like a typo to me

Comment: What is `monthArray`?

Comment: Is Vector, equal to std::vector? Not the source of your bug but you should pass as `const Vector&` to avoid copying the whole Vector. Also I would expect `TempCalculation` to return a double not a bool. Return the average and if something fails throw an exception.

Comment: Hi, monthArray = {January,February,March,April,MAy,June,July,August,September,October,November,December}

Comment: the int month is stored in the date object, GetMonth() is used to get the integer 3, however I don't think it will affect the monthArr[month] as the loop will display the month as index 2 for march

Comment: @AloysiousKok The code in `CalculateTemp()` is treating months as 0-based (January=0, December=11).  Does `Date::GetMonth()` return a 0-based or 1-based value? It makes a big difference to the code in `TempCalculation()`